# Cannot refresh the ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to use a function to check all checkboxes in a tree of checkboxes.
It is successfully checking and unchecking, BUT if I select a single checkbox then press check all, and uncheck, the single checkbox stays as it is as freeze

#### HTML

```
<fieldset id="field3">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in empdepts | groupBy:'dep_LDesc'">
      <td>
        <label ng-click="showContent = !showContent"></label>
        <details ng-open="showContent">
          <summary>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk" /> {{e[0].dep_LDesc}}</summary>
          <div ng-repeat="employee in e">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="chk"> {{employee.Sname}}
          </div>
        </details>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="all" ng-click="selectall(all)" /> All Departments</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="self" /> Self Services </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.selectall = function (all) {
    if (all) {
        $scope.chk = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.chk = false;
    }
}

LoadEmpDepts();

function LoadEmpDepts() {
    Assignments.getempdepts().then(function (response) {
        $scope.empdepts = (response.data);
        console.log($scope.empdepts);
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: use $timeout helps your problem

Comment: Could you be missing the quotes around `all`? `ng-click="selectall('all')"` and don't forget to change `if(all)` to `if('all')`.

Comment: I tried to use the $timeout but nothing is changed can you show me how to do it in my example

Comment: I tried to put single quote and it successfully checked all but fails to uncheck all

Comment: is there is a way to give priority to check-all than single check, thats all what i need, is to overwrite

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the checked property for individual elements, so the option would be to have a checked property inside each element of the array.

so whenever checkbox is checked update the property. and when checking all you make all elements checked property to be true.

```
  <label for="{{all.type}}"  ng-if="x.type === 'ALL'" >{{x.type}}</label>
```

example,

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/js81eqsb/)**

Comment: is there is a way to give priority to check-all than single check, thats all what i need, is to overwrite